# Unable to update customer data in postgreSQL

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql

I'm trying to do crud operation using pg-promises and stored procedure in PostgreSQL.

This is my code:

controller.js:

```js
const db = require("./../index.js");

exports.getAllData = async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    const data = await db.any("SELECT * FROM customers");
    res.json({ data });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
  next();
};
```

GET method

```js
exports.getData = async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    const id = req.params.id;
    const data = await db.any("SELECT * FROM customers where id=$1", [id]);
    res.json({ data });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    res.status(400).json({
      status: "failed",
      msg: error.message,
    });
  }
  next();
};
```

POST method

```js
exports.createData = async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    const name = req.body.name;
    const email = req.body.email;
    const data = await db.one("SELECT create_user($1, $2)", [name, email]);
    res.json({
      status: "success",
      data: data,
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    res.status(400).json({
      status: "failed",
      msg: error.message,
    });
  }
  next();
};
```

PATCH method :

```js
exports.updateData = async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    const id = req.params.id;
    const name = req.body.name;
    const email = req.body.email;
    // const data = await db.one('SELECT update_user($1, $2, $3) FROM customers WHERE id = $1',        [id,name,email]);
    // const data = await db.none('SELECT update_user($1, $2, $3) FROM customers WHERE id = $4',   [id, name, email, id]);
    const data = await db.any("SELECT update_user($1, $2, $3) FROM customers c WHERE c.id = $1", [
      id,
      name,
      email,
    ]);
    res.json({
      message: "success",
      data: data,
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    res.status(400).json({
      status: "failed",
      msg: error.message,
    });
  }
  next();
};
```

DELETE method

```js
exports.deleteData = async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    const id = req.params.id;
    // const data = await db.none('DELETE FROM customers WHERE id = $1', [id]);
    const data = await db.none("SELECT delete_user($1)", [id]);
    res.json({ data });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    res.status(400).json({
      status: "failed",
      msg: error.message,
    });
  }
  next();
};
```

routes.js

```js
const express = require("express");
const viewController = require("./../controllers/controller");
const router = express.Router();

router.get("/", viewController.getAllData);
router.get("/:id", viewController.getData);
router.post("/create", viewController.createData);
router.patch("/update/:id", viewController.updateData);
router.delete("/delete/:id", viewController.deleteData);

module.exports = router;
```

This is a function I have created in postgreSQL:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION create_user(name VARCHAR(50), email VARCHAR(50))
      RETURNS VOID AS $$
      BEGIN
      INSERT INTO customers (name, email)
      VALUES (name, email);
      END;
      $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

      CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION update_user(id INTEGER, name VARCHAR(50), email VARCHAR(50))
      RETURNS VOID AS $$
      BEGIN
      UPDATE customers SET name = name, email = email
      WHERE id = id;
      END;
      $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

      CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION delete_user(id INTEGER)
      RETURNS VOID AS $$
      BEGIN
      DELETE FROM customers
      WHERE id = id;
      END;
      $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

I am trying to update some data using this endpoint localhost:3000/update/:id in postman. But in response I'm getting this error:

```
{
  "status": "failed",
  "msg": "column reference \"id\" is ambiguous"
}
```

I know this question related "id is ambiguous" has been ask many times. I tried to solve this, but unable to solve this issue.

Comment: Have you tried using customers.id = id in your update function?

Comment: Or, change the parameter to something else, like customer_id:
```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION delete_user(customer_id INTEGER)
      RETURNS VOID AS $$
      BEGIN
      DELETE FROM customers
      WHERE id = customer_id;
      END;
```

Answer (score 0):

Well the `id` name in `id = id` is ambiguous - and you should be glad that it is, because if it wasn't, that condition is a tautology and would have updated/deleted *all* your rows. There are three approaches to disambiguate it:

- Just rename the function parameter:

  ```
  CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION update_user(customer_id INTEGER, new_name VARCHAR(50), new_email VARCHAR(50))
  RETURNS VOID AS $$
    BEGIN
      UPDATE customers
      SET name = new_name, email = new_email
      WHERE customer.id = customer_id;
    END;
  $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
  ```
- Use parameter numbers:

  ```
  CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION update_user(id INTEGER, name VARCHAR(50), email VARCHAR(50))
  RETURNS VOID AS $$
    BEGIN
      UPDATE customers
      SET name = $2, email = $3
      WHERE id = $1;
    END;
  $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
  ```
- Use the name of the function to qualify:

  ```
  CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION update_user(id INTEGER, name VARCHAR(50), email VARCHAR(50))
  RETURNS VOID AS $$
    BEGIN
      UPDATE customers
      SET name = update_user.name, email = update_user.email
      WHERE customers.id = update_user.id;
    END;
  $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
  ```